# Problem only when trying to align

Tags: environments, alignment

I have the following code:

```
\begin{align*}
    \eta(x, j) = 
    \begin{cases*}
        \eta_\c{C}(x, j) \quad  &\text{if } x\in \b{I}_\c{C}\\
        \eta_{\c{D}}(x, f^{-1}(j)) \quad  &\text{if } x\in \b{I}_{\c{D}} \text{ and } j\in \im{f}\\
        0 \quad  &\text{else}
    \end{cases*}
\end{align*}
```

This code compiles, but results in tons of errors at the \end{align*} line, all of the form missing {, missing $, etc.

When I delete the ampersands, there are no errors. But of course I want to align things. I'm quite confused as to what is happening.

Comment: please always post a complete document that shows the error, and say what error you get (only the first error is likley to be relevant)  `\c` for example is the text accent cedilla and will give an error in math mode unrelated to `align`

Comment: and subscripts need to be braced  `\eta_\c{C}` is the same as `\eta_{\c}  {C}`  which means (if you have defined `\c` to take an argument) you will get errors that the argument is missing

Comment: Did you redefine `\b` and `\c` as math-mode macros? How or where is `\im` defined?

Comment: I've redefined \b, \c, and \im. I've used these for a long time now, so I'm pretty sure this isn't the source of the error.

Comment: And the lack of braces was just me messing around, the same error occurs when all subscripts are fully braced

Comment: Ok, I seem to have fixed it by replacing cases* with just cases.

Comment: It is impossible for anyone to guess what is happening here,  if you have solved it locally then we should probably just close this. Next time please post the code in a form that shows the problem, note though that   redefining accent commands breaks latex's text support,. It is useless to say "the same error occurs" when you have given no indication what the error is. The only errors that anyone else can see are the ones we mentioned.

Comment: You may not have had a problem yet with a redefined `\c`, but I hope you never have a reference written by a French author with a cedilla in their name.

Answer (score 1):

Pure guessing ...

- in your code fragment you use commands `\c`, `b` and `\im` which are (except `c`, but I doubt that you like to have it here) not defined in LaTeX, so we don't know their definition
- in the second column in the `cases*` defined in `mathtools` is in the text mode, consequently math expressions in it had to be enclosed with `$` or `\(` and `´)`
- in variable indices are missed (a lot) curly braces

Assuming that `c` stand for `\mathcal`, `b` for `bm` defined in the `bm` package and `\im` has no meaning so it can be dropped, the MWE (Minimal Working Example) can be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,bm}

\begin{document}
\[ % to use align* here makes no sense
    \eta(x, j) =
    \begin{cases*}
\eta_{\mathcal{C}}(x, j)                 & if $x\in \bm{I}_{\mathcal{C}}$\\
\eta_{\mathcal{D}}(x, f^{-1}(j))\quad    & if $x\in \bm{I}_{\mathcal{D}}$ and $j\in f$\\
                                0       & else
    \end{cases*}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @egreg, thank you for correcting my missing curly braces.